# require.js not working with javascript api

Tags: javascript, api, requirejs, tumblr

I downloaded the tumblr api written in javascript from github and ran some basic code given in the readme file:

```
var tumblr = require('tumblr.js');
var client = tumblr.createClient({
  consumer_key: '<consumer key>',
  consumer_secret: '<consumer secret>',
  token: '<oauth token>',
  token_secret: '<oauth token secret>'
});
```

Of course this doesn't work even though I do exactly what the readme tells me to do. It turns out I have to download `require.js`, so I then I got this error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "tumblr.js" has not been loaded yet for context:
```

then once I loaded tumblr.js, I got this error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "fs" has not been loaded yet for context:
```

and it never ends, why can't the documentation just have a working example, I'm sick of having to spend hours on the internet looking for a simple api call to tumblr.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: I think you're expecting it to work right out of the box when it obviously has external dependencies, like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). You do know what that is and how to use it right?

Comment: In what environment are you running this? NodeJS or Browser?

Comment: yes, I'm using RequireJS, I downloaded from requirejs.org. When I use the 'readme' code example, I get the error message ""tumblr.js" and "fs" has not been loaded yet for context:"

Answer (score -1):

If you're running this on nodejs and you're getting those errors is probably that you didn't install tumblr.js. To avoid all these modules dependencies make sure you run `npm install tumblr.js` before running the examples